# Regular Expression in sas, not matching a word after a matching word

Tags: regex, sas

Maybe this is easy, but i could not find a solution.

I am working in Sas 9.3 with perl regex.
I am searching for a regular Expression, which matches only some words which are not followed by a specific other word. For example, it should match all text where you have "the car" and in all other text after this there should be no "not". (Case can be ignored, because i upcase everything in my code)

Should match

> This is not the car i want
>
> The car is green

should not match

> The car is not green
>
> This is the car i want, but its not available

One solution would be to split it in two matches:

`prxmatch("/The car/",mytext) > 0 and prxmatch("/The car.+not/",mytext)=0`

But i have to use the logic a lot of times, also in more complex cases, so i dont want to always use 2 prxmatch and instead combine the logic in one prxmatch.

I read a lot about look aheads and tried some examples, but they did not work correct, e.g.:

```
"/The Car.+[^(not)]/"
```

or

```
"/The Car.+(?!not)/"
```

or

```
"/^(?!.*not.*).*?The car.*$/"
```

1st and second return all 4 texts as results, third none result at all.

So can somebody provide me a solution for this, a simple not Operator for a word or a correct look ahead/behind Approach?

Comment: Like [`(?i)^(?=.*\bthe car\b(?!.*\bnot\b)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/pT0mP7/1)? Or [`(?i)^.*\bthe car\b(?!.*\bnot\b).*`](https://regex101.com/r/pT0mP7/2)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: What does the (?im) do? Your first example Returns an error, your second seems to work, but only if i add the (?im) at start. So, thank  you so far, but maybe you can explain me how this exactly works

Comment: Do you have a multiline string input? If yes, then I understand why `(?m)` works. `(?i)` is a case-insensitive modifier and `(?m)` is a multiline modifier making `^` match at the beginning of a line, not the start of the whole string. So, `"/^.*\bthe car\b(?!.*\bnot\b).*/im"` should work. If yes, I will post.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: K, i can remove the i and it still works with (?m). I have a textfield from database which is filled by some customers, with much more complex text then in my example. So i guess the text is multiline, altough it is shown as oneline-text in my sas-result-view. But ty very much, if you post your second example as answer, i will accept it. So the m was the problem

Comment: In SAS the options go after the final regex delimiter - so `prxparse('/<your regex>/ios);` for example.  `i` = insensitive, `o` = compile once, and I forget what S does off the top of my head.

Comment: Oh, `s` is the opposite of `m` - treat as single line.

Comment: `/s` modifier does not modify the `^` and `$`, it redefines the `.` "wildcard" metacharacter that starts matching a newline, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?im)^.*\bthe car\b(?!.*\bnot\b).*
```

The [regex demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/pT0mP7/2)

Pattern breakdown:

- `(?im)`- enable case-insensitive and multiline matching modes
- `^` - start of a line (since `(?m)` is used)
- `.*` - match 0+ any characters but a newline
- `\bthe car\b` - 2 whole words "the car" (a sequence of 2 words)
- `(?!.*\bnot\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a whole word "not" somewhere to the right of `the car`
- `.*` - the rest of the line up to the newline or end of string

Comment: I tried to simplify your solution as much as possible, "/THE CAR(?!.+NOT)/" does also work with the specific example, altough your solution is much more fail-safe for more complex constructs...

Comment: If you do not need a full line match, sure, use `\bthe car\b(?!.*\bnot\b)` (or a case-insensitive version `(?i)\bthe car\b(?!.*\bnot\b)`)